# Apache santuario in android

Tags: java, android, apache, ant

i am trying to use the librery's apache santuario, for encripting, dencripting, signing and verifing xml documents in android platform, but i can getting work beacouse the dalvikVM can't use then, this librery's  is for use in java (oracle, openjdk), i tried compile again with ant and then execute the jar command without the javax.classes (i need to use de android ones not java ones), work fines to compile the project but when i am trying to init the librery i get the same error or a java nullpointexeption, i really don't know what to do.

could anyone explain me how to use apache santuario in android app, or if anyother librery for android that do the same job

thanks